# How to select all list options from drop downlist loop through them select each option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select all list options from drop down-list loop through them select each option.

```
try {
        WebElement dropdown = RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver);
        List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='leftContent']/div[2]/d‌​iv[1]/div/select/opt‌​ion"));
        System.out.println("Dropdown Size: " + dropdownOptions.size());

        // Set value of dropdown using JS
        for (int i = 0; i < dropdownOptions.size(); i++) {
            String str = dropdownOptions.get(i).getText();
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jse.executeScript(String.format("arguments[0].value='%s';", str), dropdown);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static WebElement drpEvent(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='leftContent']/div[2]/div[1]/div/select"));          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
        return element;
    }
```

I want to select all option one by one. but here selenium not given any error and its execute next step after the above, and I' m not able to see any option is selected or not.I want to fire change event attached with that select element. And it will only change the selected item but won't fire change event attached with that.

[HTML DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFxz9.png)

**Update**

```
try {
        WebElement dropdown = RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver);
        List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = dropdown.findElements(By.xpath("//option"));
        System.out.println("Dropdown Size: " + dropdownOptions.size());

        // Set value of dropdown using JS
        for (int i = 0; i < dropdownOptions.size(); i++) {
            String str = dropdownOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            jse.executeScript(String.format("arguments[0].value='%s';", str), dropdown);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us the relevant HTML DOM please?

Comment: What is currently happening when you run your code?

Comment: Its not selected any option, I want to select all option one by one. but here selenium not given any error and its execute next step after the above. @iamkenos

Comment: @Dev So how can I write my code to execute this ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a bootstrap dropdown to me. @DarshitShah can you try hard coding any one visible text and see if it will be selected? Sample: dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Anniversary"); If it is selected, then that means the Select class can be used. Will provide an answer depending on the result.

Comment: @DarshitShah We don't have a visibility to `RemindersElements` and `drpEvent`. Can you consider showing us more of the HTML DOM in the Question area please? Thanks

Comment: dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Anniversary"); its not select "Anniversary" default value is remain as selected. @iamkenos

Comment: RemindersElements is my class name "public class RemindersElements" and drpEvent is method name "public static WebElement drpEvent(WebDriver driver) {" @Dev

Comment: So can you tell us what are you exactly doing through `Select dropdown = new Select(RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver));`

Comment: Select dropdown = new Select(RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver)) - Its only get xpath for dropdown, @Dev

Comment: @DarshitShah If your original question is answered, please be considerate enough to accept the answer and start a different thread with the problem you're currently facing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using a similar `<select>` dropdown like what you have in your page:

```
public void foo() {
    try {
        Select dropdown = new Select(RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver));
        System.out.println("Dropdown Size: " + dropdown.getOptions().size());

        for (int i = 0; i < dropdown.getOptions().size(); i++) {
            String text = dropdown.getOptions().get(i).getText();
            dropdown.selectByVisibleText(text);
            System.out.println("Option " + (i + 1) + ":" + text);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Some things you might want to check:

See if the `dropdown` instance created from `RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver)` is valid. Print the total options. Based on your screenshot, it should print 6.

Your loop should start with index `0`

move your try catch block outside the loop so you can debug properly

Reference page:
http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/dropdown/default.html

**UPDATE 1:**
Few other things you can try listed below. These should work as long as your `RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver)` returns a valid element.

```
public void bar() {
    try {
        WebElement dropdown = RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver);
        List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = dropdown.findElements(By.xpath("//option"));
        System.out.println("Dropdown Size: " + dropdownOptions.size());

        // Click the dropdown and click each option one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < dropdownOptions.size(); i++) {
            dropdown.click();
            dropdownOptions.get(i).click();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void baz() {
    try {
        WebElement dropdown = RemindersElements.drpEvent(driver);
        List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = dropdown.findElements(By.xpath("//option"));
        System.out.println("Dropdown Size: " + dropdownOptions.size());

        // Set value of dropdown using JS
        for (int i = 0; i < dropdownOptions.size(); i++) {
            String str = dropdownOptions.get(i).getText();
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jse.executeScript(String.format("arguments[0].value='%s';", str), dropdown);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Add this in your RemindersElements class:

```
public static List <WebElement> drpEventOpts(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='leftContent']/div[2]/div[1]/div/select/option"));          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
        return elements;
    }
```

Then replace this line:

```
List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = RemindersElements.drpEventOpts(driver);
```

Comment: its give me below output but not single option is select,            Dropdown Size: 6
Option 1:Occasion
Option 2:Holiday
Option 3:Birthday
Option 4:New Baby
Option 5:Anniversary
Option 6:Wedding                                                                                              Still my issue is not resolve... @iamkenos

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try the other 2 approaches. Thank you.

Comment: I did a minor correction on baz(). It should be `jse.executeScript(String.format("arguments[0].value='%s';", str), dropdown);` Please use the updated answer.

Comment: baz() - only change "Occasion" to "Holiday" but not click all the options which mentioned in HTML DOM... and give below error 
Dropdown Size: 102
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' @iamkenos

Comment: bar() - is gives below error Dropdown Size: 102 org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not visible Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'  @iamkenos

Comment: will you be able to share the url?

Comment: try changing this line accordingly: `List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='leftContent']/div[2]/div[1]/div/select/option"));`

Comment: its given me an error after update "List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='leftContent']/div[2]/d‌​iv[1]/div/select"));" JavaScript error: chrome://marionette/content/proxy.js, line 228: TypeError: l is undefined
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' @iamkenos

Comment: its given me an error after update "List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='leftContent']/div[2]/d‌​iv[1]/div/select/opt‌​ion"));" JavaScript error: chrome://marionette/content/proxy.js, line 228: TypeError: l is undefined
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' @iamkenos

Comment: can you update your question with the current code you have now?

Comment: I updated my answer. This should work. If it's not working still, you may want to debug step by step what is happening in your script. try the update for both bar and baz. I'm not in front of my pc now so replies may be delayed.

Comment: Added in RemindersElements . but I'm not understand where I need to add List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = RemindersElements.drpEventOpts(driver); @iamkenos

Comment: line 3 of bar and baz. replace the instance declaration of dropdownOptions with that line.

Comment: When I do its give me red line under "dropdownOptions" and an error is: Duplicate local variable dropdownOptions, now second red line under "dropdown" and an error is: dropdown cannot be resolved. @iamkenos

Comment: Got below error 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-FOGUK5ND', ip: '192.168.1.49', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver @iamkenos

Comment: Can you tell me which line you're getting that error? Also, have you tried for both bar and baz?

Comment: This line give me an error : List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = RemindersElements.drpEventOpts(driver); Yes I tried both bar and baz. @imkenos

Comment: Sorry man, I can't help you further without the URL. You'll have to debug this error.

Comment: can you tell me what browser are you using for this test?

Comment: Can you please provide your updates properly? Kindly update your question with the stack trace of the error you're currently getting.

Comment: Please see "UPDATE" code now I want to fire javascript event for every selected option. @iamkenos

Comment: Your update does not show the error you are getting. Which line is giving the error and what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: No error is showing, but I want to fire event when selected option is change. and its not working, only select all option one by one is working. @iamkenos

Comment: Confused with your updates. Can you please answer these questions: 1) What do you mean by not working - if it's not working it will either give you an error, do something else that is not intended, or nothing will happen. Please explain clearly 2) what do you mean by select option one by one is working? 3) Why did you decide to use javascript executor, is the second solution (bar()) not working?

Comment: Its execute all the code and no error is displayed, there is one dropdown which have 5 options and every option have unique event when we select that option, For Example if I select 2nd option then all the text box hide and only one dropdown is display now i select 3rd option the dropdown is hide and textbox is display. this thing is not working when we select other option the event is not fire. only option is changed. @iamkenos

Comment: That means the loop to select all options are working, correct? But the events to trigger field dependencies are not getting fired. If your original question is answered and the solution is working, please accept the answer and start a different thread stating the other problem. Thank you.

Comment: My question is not full-fill. I have written this in my question "I want to select all option one by one. but here selenium not given any error and its execute next step after the above, and I' m not able to see any option is selected or not.I want to fire change event attached with that select element. And it will only change the selected item but won't fire change event attached with that." @iamkenos

Comment: Good luck, mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public static void  checkDropdownAllOption(WebDriver driver,WebElement lelement)
{
    Select oSelect = new Select(lelement);
    java.util.List <WebElement> elementCount = oSelect.getOptions();
    int iSize = elementCount.size();
    String [] arrdropdown= new String [iSize];          
    for (int j = 0; j < iSize; j++) 
    {
        arrdropdown[j]=elementCount.get(j).getText();
    }

    WebElement mySelectElm = lelement;              
    Select mySelect= new Select(mySelectElm);       
    for (int i = 0; i < arrdropdown.length; i++) 
    {
        mySelect.selectByVisibleText(arrdropdown[i]);
    }   
}
```